# Check existence of global function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, introspection

Is it possible to detect if some **global function** (not class method) is defined (in iOS)? Something like `respondsToSelector` in a class...

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a Swift function—or a C function imported from Apple's frameworks?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I wonder, can you detect either of them?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Everything is helpful.

Comment: if its global function, so why do you care about checking its existence. Just curious

Comment: @Sulthan See my answer.

Comment: @HossamGhareeb That's commonly needed to check availability of functions from Apple's frameworks. Some functions are supported only on later OS versions.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe In Swift we are supposed to use `#available` for that.

Comment: @Sulthan There's a slight difference: `#available` can only check for OS versions. The question is explicitly about checking the existence of a global function. Anyway, for the common use case (Apple frameworks) the result is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swift currently does not support looking up global functions.

For C functions (most global functions from Apple's frameworks are C functions) there are at least two ways:

- using a weakly linked symbol
- the dynamic linker API: `dlopen`

Both check dynamically (at runtime) if a symbol can be found.

Here's an example that checks if `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` (introduced with iOS 4) is available:

```
void UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize size, BOOL opaque, CGFloat scale) __attribute__((weak));

static inline BOOL hasUIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions() {
    return UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL;
}
```

Here's the same check, using `dlsym`:

```
#import <dlfcn.h>

static inline BOOL hasUIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions() {
    return dlsym(RTLD_SELF, "UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions") != NULL;
}
```

The advantage of using `dlsym` is that you don't need a declaration and that it's easily portable to Swift.

Comment: Now I remember I actually have used the weak linking myself before. I am not really sure if that would work for Swift globals though.

Comment: @Sulthan It wouldn't, because Objective-C cannot see Swift globals. But perhaps that is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Sulthan Swift's name mangling is preventing simple symbol lookup.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible in Swift.

Even `respondsToSelector` uses the Obj-C runtime and can be used only for functions available in Obj-C.

Comment: How will you get past the compiler if the function does not exist?

Comment: @Feldur That's why we have `#available`.

Comment: @Feldur You can always declare a function (as `extern`, but that's the default) and then leave it up to the dynamic linker to resolve the symbol. That's what happens all of the time when linking to system frameworks.

Comment: Wa's the question not relative to doing this in Swift? Extern does not seem to be a swift keyword